# Grails Resources Plugin: Defining resources inside shared plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a Grails plugin that contains static resources (images, css, js, etc) that are shared across several Grails apps. I am having problems getting the Resources plugin to work, however. Inside my shared plugin /conf I have a AppResources.groovy file that defines all the bundles, etc.

I add my shared plugin to my app, but when I start the app none of the resources are found:

```
Resource not found: /less/main.less
Resource not found: /js/application.js
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to specify "plugin" attribute for each resource (e.g. resource url: [plugin: 'plugin-name', dir: 'js', file: 'application.js'])?